# In which sub-region is the Team Foundation Service hosted build controller?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-devops

Team Foundation Service offer a [hosted build controller](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/hosted-build-controller-in-vs.aspx). I've got builds and unit tests up and working with this. Now I'd like to run integration tests that include a database. I would like to set up an Azure SQL Database to fill this role, however, I don't want to pay for cross-sub-region data charges so would like to create the SQL Database in the same sub-region as the build controller.

Hence the question: In which sub-region is the Team Foundation Service hosted build controller?

And the follow on questions: Is that guaranteed not to change? Can it be 'pinned' for a specific project?

Comment: This is not guaranteed to change in the future.  I actually also thought that we hosted our cloud build system in the US East datacenter.

Comment: I did read that when more sub-regions are introduced we will be offered the choice of which sub-region we would like to host the controller. Of course, this doesn't mean that in the mean time they couldn't move it of US West and onto US East, so use this knowledge with caution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer eventually: **US West region**. This is as per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e9b986da-228d-437b-adc1-2eaaed6e1858/in-which-azure-region-does-tfs-preview-reside